# How to export/import or access functions defined in an encapsulating function, from outside the encapsulating function in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scope, export

I'm trying to add code to a module and having trouble with exports and scope.

I have a file like this:

```
export enum foo {
  ctl = '0',
  dta = '1',
} 
const EncapSulatingFunc = (props: any) => {
const func1 = (uid: string, text: string, ts: string) => { ... }
const func2 = (
    uid: string,
    text: string,
    ts: string,
    local: boolean,
  ) => {...}
const func3 = async (msg: string) => {...}
useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [someprops.channel, somprops.appId, isGoing);
render(...)
}; // end of EncapSulatingFunc
export default EncapSulatingFunc;
```

I can access the enum outside this file, and outside the Encapsulationg Func.
I cannot access func1,2 or 3 outside the encapsulating function either in the file or from other files when importing this module.

Is there a way to make func1,2 or 3 available outside of  EncapSulatingFunc() ?

Thanks!

Comment: is `EncapSulatingFunc` a react functional component?

Comment: Hi @Hozeis, I modified to show the export. It is defined and exported as shown.

Comment: By the way if I change the const func1 = ... to export const func1, I get the error that exports must happen at the top level.

Comment: if you are using a functional component, take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Comment: I tried it with class and as defined, but I cannot refer to  functions within the class or functional element. from outside it.  Should it be something like export { EncapSulatingFunc.func1 } ? I will check out your article.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I would up moving the function definitions outside the encapsulating function to make this work.